# Cheating in open sourced projects which use GameCenter

Tags: ios, git, github, game-center

I have an AppStore game which uses GameCenter to store best scores. After a while I decided to open source it, used git as my version control system and published it on GitHub.

Two or three days later I saw scores which were too big to be real. Yes, I have used intervals for scores in GameCenter, but I took an upper bound higher than the actual scores can be.

First I thought about removing leaderboard id from my source code, but... it was to painful for me to remove its name from each commit without touching other changes in that file and in that same moment to allow my project to be build without any errors and warnings, I wanted to make this project/game just work when somebody runs it.

So, is there any way to prevent cheating? Are there any mechanisms which prevent apps signed by other developers publish scores in my apps' GameCenter leaderboards?

Comment: Sorta goes without saying that open sourcing the code provides a blueprint for cheating.  I am mystified, however, that people would even do this.  If you're a jewel thief, at least you're stealing something tangible.  The only thing that you can call a person who goes to great effort to steal fake internet points is stupid.  I don't understand the incentive.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I know its stupid, but there are two major things I wanted/want to do: open source my games so others can see how it works, create their own etc etc, the second one - I like open source and I think it can help others to make cool things. But... sometimes there appear cheaters, don't know why they do this but its bad, bad for others who owned their points by gaming, not by cheating.